# Access folder outside of webapp

Tags: tomcat

I am having a hard time trying to configure Apache Tomcat 8 to access a folder what stand outside of webapp. I tried multiple things including context to the `server.xml` and then learned that this isn't the correct way to do it because `docBase` refers to the location of a web application.

I also tried adding a `/` to the project properties > web project settings: contect root. I have `node_modules` folder at the root level of the project. I get a 404 error on all my script tags trying to access this folder.

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JS file **outside webapp**, there are only a solution, use **absolute path**.

By some ways, you maybe put js file inside webapp, you will do something like this:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Placing the folder inside Web app does work but I am trying to do it outside the webapp. Looks like I need to look and see if i can tell maven to install the node_modules into the webapp folder.